# How a slave wake up the HOST during USB BUS in sleep mode

Tags: usb

If there is a possible, both HOST and slave are in sleep status, but USB physical connection is permanently (USB bus is sleep as well) and then, slave can wake up HOST via USB bus?

Answer (score 0):

There is a wakeup signal on USB bus. A host can suspend the bus; a device can react to some external event, send remote wakeup and activate the host.

For example, a USB hub with no devices attached will get suspended by the OS right after enumeration. However, when a device gets connected to a hub it will send a wakeup to have the host activate the bus and enumerate the device.